# Program doesn't run. Says I am trying to assign value to a pointer

Tags: c

I am trying to read file into an array, but the code doesn't run. Says I am trying to assign value to a pointer.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *ifile;
    float num;
    float*numbers[8001];
    float pointer = numbers;
    int i = 0;

    ifile = fopen("lotsOfNumbers.txt", "r");
    if (ifile == NULL) {
        printf("File not found!! Exiting.\n");
    }
    else {
        while (fscanf(ifile, "%f ", &num) != EOF) {

            //printf("I read %d from the file. \n", num);
            numbers[i] = &num;

            if (i < 8801) {
                i++;
            }
            else return 0;
        }
    }

    fclose(ifile);
}
```

Comment: What is mean "the code doesn't run"? Error or wrong output?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: *`float pointer=numbers;`* – What do you think you do here?

Comment: *`numbers[i] = &num;`* – and here?

Comment: Hint: If you cannot even compile your program, it is pointless to say it does not run.

Answer (score 2):

There are many errors in your code. You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE *ifile;
  float num;
  float numbers[8001];    // you just need an array of float, no pointers needed
  int i = 0;

  ifile = fopen("lotsOfNumbers.txt", "r");
  if (ifile == NULL) {
    printf("File not found!! Exiting.\n");
  }
  else {
    while (fscanf(ifile, "%f ", &num) != EOF) {  // &num instead of num

      printf("I read %f from the file.\n", num); // use %f for printing a float, not %d
      numbers[i] = num;

      if (i < 8001) {    // 8001 instead of 8801
        i++;             // using a constant or a #define avoids this kind of errors
      }
      else
        return 0;
    }

    fclose(ifile);   // close file only if it has been opened sucessfully
  }
    // fclose(ifile);  // that was the wrong place for fclose
}
```

Explanations are in the comments.